# Items assigned to iteration not showing on sprint board

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have a set of features that have been assigned to an iteration but when clicking on the board for the current sprint they are not shown.

Items assigned to sprint:
[image: Iteration view]

Current Sprint Board:
[image: Current Sprint View]

How can I get these features to show on the sprint board?

Comment: What server are you using? On-premise TFS server or Visual Studio Team Service? And which template are you using? Agile or Scrum?

Comment: Team Services and it's Agile

Comment: Can you see them from "Stories" board?

Comment: Yeah I can see them in there no problem

Comment: Can you share the screenshot about the "Iterations" and "Areas" settings of ZonalDevelopersToolkit Team?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sprint board will only show you Product Backlog Items (or User Stories, if you're using the Agile template), Bugs, and Tasks. The Feature work item type is intended to be for organization of longer-term work that will take User Storys/PBIs and possibly multiple sprints to complete.

Comment: Good to know but my user story isn't in there either

Comment: For the user story, my guess would be that work item's Area also needs to match up with the backlog's configured area paths

Comment: I think this is a missing feature in TFS. We organize our work in Stages and Sprints. A feature belong to a stage and an user story to a sprint. I can assign manually a iteration to the feature but not via drag and drop.

Comment: This still seems to be a bug - Epic will not display on backlog at Epics level unless assigned to a sprint. This is on new test project using Agile process.